# How to invoke sequence while inserting new record into postgresql table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How do I invoke a postgresql sequence while inserting new row into a table?

I want to do something like this:

```
insert into biz_term(
  biz_term_id, 
  biz_term_name, 
  ) 
values(SELECT nextval(idsequence)',
'temp'
);
```

I want to do it because when I am trying to insert new record into `biz_term` table then sequence `idsequence` is not getting invoked directly.  How to invoke it?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You got it almost. You don't need the SELECT in there:

```
insert into biz_term(
  biz_term_id, 
  biz_term_name, 
) 
values(
 nextval('idsequence'),
 'temp'
);
```

Any reasons you did not specify the biz_term_id as `serial` (or `bigserial`) which handles that automatically for you?

Comment: To answer your question - I am using this technique since I want my serial to continue counting from one table to another table.

Comment: what is 'idsequence'? Throws "does not exist"

Comment: @JMess: it's the name of the sequences as used in the question. Obviously if your sequence has a different name, you need to use that name

Answer (score 3):

Even though it's a bit old topic, I would like to point out that one good reason to go with `BIGINT`, against `BIGSERIAL` is if you are using hibernate.
Here is the article:
https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-serial-column-hibernate-identity/

As the article points out,

> Using a SEQUENCE generator is a better alternative since the
> identifier can be generated prior to executing the INSERT statement

Posting an answer, cause i'm not yet eligible to comment :/ . I apologize in advance in case you find it inappropriate.

Comment: A `bigserial` does use a sequence to generate the values.

Comment: Yes inded it uses. But the value of a bigserial, will not be availabe to hibernate, because in the case of bigserial, bigserial is generated in the database - thus is not visible to hibernate! Using `bigserial` in postgres, is the same using identity (auto_increment) regarding hibernate. So, it is recommended to use `big int` in db, and have a generator in hibernate and use "true" sequences. I have a left a link that it might be better for you to understand what i'm saying.

Comment: Well Hibernate could simply use `nextval()` for the sequence behind the serial, but I guess it's too much to ask from an obfuscation layer. Using a (native) sequence is much more efficient, scalable and concurrency safe than anything the obfuscation layer could implement on their own

Comment: As far as i know, the native sequence is the one that we have when we have a sequence stored in our database. Please correct me if i'm wrong on this. What i was trying to tell in my previous comments is that, hibernate "prefers the native" ---> and by prefer i mean that hibernate will use nextval() when we use native sequence! :)
Hibernate will NOT use nextval() if we use bigserial or serial that is not a native sequence.